# JQuery datepicker doesnt return mm/dd/yy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to convert a date to dd/mm/yy formatusing JQuery datepicker. But I ended up with dd/mm/yyyy. Below is the code I tried -

```
chkIn = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", cinDate); where cinDate is Thu Aug 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530
```

`chkIn` is `29/08/2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "mm/dd/y", cinDate );
```

[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Answer (score 1):

[Read the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

> y - year (two digit)
>
> yy - year (four digit)

So use `chkIn = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/y", cinDate);`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use  `"dd/mm/y"` instead of `"dd/mm/yy"`

```
chkIn = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/y", cinDate);
```

> $.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings )

Format a date into a string value with a specified format.

```
The format can be combinations of the following:

d - day of month (no leading zero)
dd - day of month (two digit)
o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
oo - day of the year (three digit)
D - day name short
DD - day name long
m - month of year (no leading zero)
mm - month of year (two digit)
M - month name short
MM - month name long
y - year (two digit)
yy - year (four digit)
@ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
! - Windows ticks (100ns since 01/01/0001)
'...' - literal text
'' - single quote
anything else - literal text
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Answer (score 1):

I think, your code must work:

```
var cinDate = new Date(); // it must be a date object
var current_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', cinDate);
```

It works for me.

Look at this:   [jsfiddle_example_for_datepicker_formatdate](http://jsfiddle.net/XJSVh/)